# How to limit network usage for concrete application in linux that is running in it?

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth-control

I'm looking for something like nice for cpu, but for network usage that will limit application network consumption to level that will configure.

I have problems with xapian-replicate-server that is consuming 80 % of my network. It's causing mysql connections problem (mysql server is working on this machine too). I can't move xapian or mysql to other machine so i need to limit xapian network usage to a decent level.

Is there any tool that will help me do this ?

Comment: Most managed switches (even low-cost ones) feature QoS so that you can prioritize traffic.

Comment: This is an old example with iproute and iptables (you may have netfilter already but it should be similar): http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.fullnat.intro.html

Comment: But, netfilter == iptables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tc`, `iptables` etc can all do this, but just to be different:

You can use Linux kernel feature `cgroups` and its `net_cls` module for limiting xapian-replicate-server. Something like this should do:

```
mount -t cgroup -onet net /sys/fs/cgroup
cd /sys/fs/cgroup
mkdir xapian-replicate-server
/bin/echo $$ > xapian-replicate-server/tasks
/bin/echo 2048 > xapian-replicate-server/net.tcp
/bin/echo 4096 > xapian-replicate-server/net.tot
however_you_launch_xapian-replicate-server
```

This would create a new cgroup for Xapian and give it total of 2048 kilobytes/s TCP traffic bandwidth and 4096 kilobytes/s of total whatever network traffic bandwidth.

Comment: You should mount the `cgroup` filesystem under `/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls` if your distribution does not already do so.

Comment: @Sam Morris: Oops! Fixed my comment :)

Comment: This cgroup no longer functions that way. You need to add a series of qdiscs, classes and filters and then mark the class you want that cgroups traffic to go into with `net_cls.classid`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like "trickle" could work for you: http://monkey.org/~marius/trickle/